# cloudwatch log subscription filter to kinesis on terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-kinesis, terraform-provider-aws

I have a problem with log subscription on aws with terraform. I'd like my lambda log, once this in cloudwatch, be possible to sending to **Kinesis Stream**. I created a role and policy that make it possible, and created a log subscription. But, when I try to create the resources, I receive the message: **Could not deliver test message to specified Kinesis stream. Check if the given kinesis stream is in ACTIVE state**.

Here is my policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kinesis:PutRecord",
                "kinesis:PutRecords"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-1:accountID:stream/stream-name"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is my log subscription:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter" "name_lambdafunction_logfilter" {
  name            = "name_lambdafunction_logfilter"
  role_arn        = "arn:aws:iam::accountID:role/cloudwatch_to_streams_role"
  log_group_name  = "/aws/lambda/${var.project}-name-${terraform.workspace}"
  filter_pattern  = "{ $.application = * }"
  destination_arn = "arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-1:accountID:stream/stream-name"
  distribution    = "ByLogStream"
}
```

Comment: What role is the policy attached to, and what's its trust relatinoship?

Comment: As mentioned above it would be useful if you edited your question to include the role definition and the IAM policy attachment. Ideally your question should contain a [mcve] that allows others to run things and reproduce the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error "Could not deliver test message to specified Kinesis stream. Check if the given kinesis stream is in ACTIVE state." in my AWS sandbox account, when I was trying to connect a new log group to a kinesis data stream using a subscription.

I followed the instructions in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html and that got things working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).